# how to locate elements by xpath based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I want to grab only those h3 titles with red arrow who contain span of class "BOLD NEGATIVE" in blue arrow.

[image]

I want to scrape the data of eBay website in particular but I am having problem because simple xpath cannot work on this when we require a condition there.

Comment: Which value exactly you want to extract?

Comment: That in the red arrow but condition is that there should be a span of class = BOLD NEGATIVE in the blue arrow.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the solution by myself :)
here it is

//span[@class='BOLD NEGATIVE']//ancestor::div[@class='s-item__info clearfix']/a/h3

Thanks Guys